# CVAT (computer vision annotation tool) export impossible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I'm using [cvat](https://github.com/opencv/cvat) for segmentation annotation and am very impressed by it. However, it seems that I am unable to export my annotated data set. Upon loading the tasks page (http://localhost:7080/tasks/1), I receive the error message:

```
Could not get formats from the server. Error: Network error.
```

From the developer console i can see that several requests fail upon

```
localhost:8080/auto_annotation/meta/get
localhost:8080/tensorflow/annotation/meta/get
localhost:8080/tensorflow/segmentation/meta/get
localhost:8080/analytics/app/kibana
```

All these return 404. And finally one which is probably causing the error message

```
localhost:8080/api/v1/server/dataset/formats
```

Where no specific eror code is displayed.

My issue is that when trying to "Export as a dataset", no options to download appear. The button does nothing.

I am very new to docker and I don't know whether the issue can be caused by my docker setup or the installation of cvat itself.

For the same reason I didn't know I had to run the container with a volume and so now I am in rist of losing my work.

So far I have tried to commit the running docker container, save it as tarball, and moving it to another computer with the same cvat installation, where exporting worked before. However, I receive a similar error and not even the login page works.

'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/self', status: (failed), type: xhr, initiator: xhr.js:160

I have also tried to explore the exported image with bash, but I cannot seem to find any saved data of the annotations anywhere.

If I rebuild (`docker-compose build`), as described in the installation guide, will my data get lost?

Is there any other way to export my data?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too. I have built the docker container on a virtual machine. Unfortunately, the machine has no avx support. All other machines, to which I installed CVAT, do support avx and the mentioned error does not appear. So I assume it is an issue due to missing avx support.

I hope this information will help someone.